# Converting Fixed width file to delimited file in Azure Data Factory - Mapping Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have ten files (.txt) in ADLS. I have their metadata in Azure SQL db.
My Metadata looks like this :

[image]

I am trying to convert the fixed width file into delimited files with header using Mapping Data flow.
Only reference from Microsoft on this topic is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-fixed-width.

But I have multiple files with varying number of columns.
Is there any way I can pass this metadata from table to Derived columns transformation.
I know it is easily achievable with Databricks. But I have to do this with Dataflow.

Any references or pointers will be really helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the Table Name column represents the names of files (.txt)?

Comment: Yes. File name is T1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can pass this metadata from table to Derived columns transformation.

Please follow my steps:

1. I linked the **DataSource** to my ADLS's test file folder which contains T1.txt,T2.txt and T3.txt. It's important to give a name to the **Column to store file name**, so that we can get the file metadata(Where the data comes from).
   [image]
   In the Data preview tab, we can see the info:
   [image]
2. Then I use the expression `replace(replace(FileName,'/',''),'.txt','')` to replace the redundant strings.
   [image]
3. In the **SQLSource**, I created a table following your example.
   [image]
4. Then I joined the two sources.
   [image]
5. I use the expression `substring(toString({_col0_}), startPosition, data_length)`  to split the string according to metadata.
   [image]
6. The result shows:
   [image]

Hope my answer is helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort @Joseph Xu. Let me try and update.

Comment: Hi @Joseph Xu, Thank you. The solution worked perfect for one record files. In your example, I believe , you have single record 12345678 in each file. But, if my file size is say 300MB and I have around 900 files, will this be efficient?

Comment: Also, if need to write this in a file with header like:

Comment: Col1, Col2, Col3

1,23,3
31,23,4

Comment: Yes, for testing I have single record 12345678 in each file，I haven't considered other situations. Depending on what you describe, it may be a little complicated.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. Any tips for this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63633959/pivoting-based-on-row-number-in-azure-data-factory-mapping-data-flow