# Pivoting based on Row Number in Azure Data Factory - Mapping Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure and am trying to see if the below result is achievable with data factory / mapping data flow without Databricks.

I have my csv file with this sample data :

[image]

I have following data in my table :

[image]

My expected data/ result:

[image]

Which transformations would be helpful to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, you have the RowNumber column, you can use [pivot activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-pivot) to do row-column pivoting.
I used your sample data to made a test as follows:

1. My **Projection** tab is like this:
   [image]
2. My **DataPreview** is like this:
   [image]
3. In the **Pivot1** activity, we select **Table_Name** and **Row_Number** columns to group by. If you don't want **Table_Name** column, you can delete it here.
   [image]
4. At **Pivote key** tab, we select **Col_Name** column.
   [image]
5. At **Pivoted columns**, we must select a agrregate function to aggregate the **Value** column, here I use max().
   [image]
6. The result shows:
   [image]

Please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

---

**update:**

1. The data source like this:
   [image]
2. The result shows as you saied, ADF sorts the column alphabetically.It seems no way to customize sorting:
   [image]
3. But when we done the sink activity, it will auto mapping into your sql result table.
   [image]

Comment: Hi Joseph. I followed the mentioned steps. My column is not ordered. Say, My data projection shows Table_Name, Row_Number, C4, C6,C5.. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Hi Madan, I've tried serveral times. It seems to be sorted automatically. Please see my **update**. I have no additional operations.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. ADF sorts the column alphabetically, My original column names(in order) are C_STE, C_ANO, C_BTEC, C_ORDER.  So, after sorting , it is giving me in C_ANO,C_BTEC etc. Is there any way I can give col order in pivoting so tat the column order is maintained?

Comment: It seems no way to customize sorting. But when we done the sink activity, it will auto mapping into your sql result table. So it is no matter how the ADF is sorted, that's right?Please see my **update**.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But my sink is not a table but csv. But will load into a temp table and then move to csv. Thanks a lot. I have done the same with databricks. Is there any way I can compare the performance / efficiency of  two pipelines?

Comment: You are welcome Madan. I am also constantly learning ADF and I only know a little about databricks. Let's learn from each other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220772/discussion-between-madan-and-joseph-xu).